# Soft artisans excel writer cannot cope with large workbook

Tags: officewriter

I am trying to open a workbook and loop through each sheet using office writer  - the workbook has over 30 sheets, but the office writer workbook object thinks there are only 6.  There something weird in the workbook that is breaking office writer  I cant attach the workbook to this post so I am hoping someone from SA will assist marcus.scholz@riotinto.com

Comment: What version of office writer are you using. There was a bug fix around the early versions of officewriter 8.3 that fixed a bug with the symptoms you are describing.

Comment: ExcelWriter can handle workbooks with 100s of worksheets.  Behavior like this doesn't have to do with the size of the workbook.  It is usually caused by ExcelWriter having trouble parsing something in a worksheet and then not adding that sheet to the Worksheets collection.

Comment: Thanks Aviva M.  Are you from soft artisans?  If so, are you interested in testing this workbook?  There may be a bug in office writer.  I can send it to you if you like.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the answer here is don't use soft artisans.  I have since switched to Aspose Cells and its a much more robust product.